# Column width change/shrink to accommodate another column after onclick button- React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React. I've a page with a table. Once button is clicked, a detail form should display on the right side of the table. The table is set in column with grid-10, and needed to be take most of the page grid column. The detail form is set in column with grid-4.

It's not going to be reflected but here is the link to the playground code: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-grothendieck-bkygv?file=/src/table.js

Any help (css, bootstrap,etc.) is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I added `bootstrap` to your sandbox in order for the grid to work.

Secondly, based on the `active`'s value, `div` needs to change class.

Check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dust-21puz)

Comment: Wow, is it a toggle between two classnames? So in first state it is on col-10 then change to col-8?

Comment: yes. by comparing the value of the `active` variable